# How to display paragraph next to another paragraph without flexbox?

Tags: html, css

I need to reach below effect without using flexbox:

```
<div style="display: flex">
    <p>Paragraph1</p>
    <p style="margin-left: auto;">Paragraph2</p>
</div>
```

Is there possibility to make it only with float and text align?

Answer (score 0):

Could try `grid`:

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Paragraph1</p>
  <p>Paragraph2</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.two { width: 30em; max-width: 100%; }
.two p { display: inline-block; max-width: 50%; }
.two p:nth-child(1) { float:left; }
.two p:nth-child(2) { float:right; }
```

```html
<div class="two">
    <p>This is the first paragraph of two.</p>
    <p>This is the second paragraph of two.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Solutions without explanations are never helpful.

Comment: It's a bit redundant to use inline-block _and_ floats.